# Dealing with request rate limits, MusicBrainz API

Tags: python, api, request, musicbrainz

**Question:** Is a time delay a good way of dealing with request rate limits?

I am very new to requests, APIs and web services. I am trying to create a web service that, given an ID, makes a request to MusicBrainz API and retrieves some information. However, apparently I am making too many requests, or making them too fast. In the last line of the code, if the `delay` parameter is set to `0`, this error will appear:

```
{'error': 'Your requests are exceeding the allowable rate limit. Please see http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/XMLWebService for more information.'}
```

And looking into that link, I found out that:

`The rate at which your IP address is making requests is measured. If that rate is too high, all your requests will be declined (http 503) until the rate drops again. Currently that rate is (on average) 1 request per second.`

Therefore I thought, okey, I will insert a time delay of 1 second, and it will work. And it worked, but I guess there are nicer, neater and smarter ways of dealing with such a problem. Do you know one?

CODE:

```
####################################################
################### INSTRUCTIONS ###################
####################################################

'''
This script runs locally and returns a JSON formatted file, containing
information about the release-groups of an artist whose MBID must be provided.
'''

#########################################
############ CODE STARTS ################
#########################################


#IMPORT PACKAGES
#All of them come with Anaconda3 installation, otherwise they can be installed with pip 
import requests
import json
import math
import time


#Base URL for looking-up release-groups on musicbrainz.org
root_URL = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/'

#Parameters to run an example
offset = 10
limit = 1
MBID = '65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab'



def collect_data(MBID, root_URL):

    '''
    Description: Auxiliar function to collect data from the MusicBrainz API

    Arguments: 
        MBID - MusicBrainz Identity of some artist.
        root_URL - MusicBrainz root_URL for requests

    Returns:
        decoded_output - dictionary file containing all the information about the release-groups 
        of type album of the requested artist
    '''

    #Joins paths. Note: Release-groups can be filtered by type.
    URL_complete = root_URL + 'release-group?artist=' + MBID + '&type=album' + '&fmt=json'

    #Creates a requests object and sends a GET request
    request = requests.get(URL_complete)

    assert request.status_code == 200

    output = request.content            #bits file 
    decoded_output = json.loads(output) #dict file

    return decoded_output 



def collect_releases(release_group_id, root_URL, delay = 1):

    '''
    Description: Auxiliar function to collect data from the MusicBrainz API

    Arguments: 
        release_group_id - ID of the release-group whose number of releases is to be extracted
        root_URL - MusicBrainz root_URL for requests

    Returns:
        releases_count - integer containing the number of releases of the release-group
    '''

    URL_complete = root_URL + 'release-group/' + release_group_id + '?inc=releases' + '&fmt=json'

    #Creates a requests object and sends a GET request
    request = requests.get(URL_complete)

    #Parses the content of the request to a dictionary
    output = request.content            
    decoded_output = json.loads(output) 

    #Time delay to not exceed MusicBrainz request rate limit
    time.sleep(delay)

    releases_count = 0

    if 'releases' in decoded_output:
        releases_count = len(decoded_output['releases'])
    else:
        print(decoded_output)
        #raise ValueError(decoded_output)


    return releases_count



def paginate(store_albums, offset, limit = 50):

    '''
    Description: Auxiliar function to paginate results

    Arguments: 
        store_albums - Dictionary containing information about each release-group
        offset - Integer. Corresponds to starting album to show.
        limit - Integer. Default to 50. Maximum number of albums to show per page

    Returns:
        albums_paginated - Paginated albums according to specified limit and offset
    '''

    #Restricts limit to 150 
    if limit > 150:
         limit = 150

    if offset > len(store_albums['albums']):
        raise ValueError('Offset is greater than number of albums')

    #Apply offset    
    albums_offset = store_albums['albums'][offset:]

    #Count pages
    pages = math.ceil(len(albums_offset) / limit)
    albums_limited = []

    if len(albums_offset) > limit:
        for i in range(pages):
            albums_limited.append(albums_offset[i * limit : (i+1) * limit])
    else:
        albums_limited = albums_offset

    albums_paginated = {'albums' : None}
    albums_paginated['albums'] = albums_limited


    return albums_paginated



def post(MBID, offset, limit, delay = 1):


    #Calls the auxiliar function 'collect_data' that retrieves the JSON file from MusicBrainz API
    json_file = collect_data(MBID, root_URL) 

    #Creates list and dictionary for storing the information about each release-group 
    album_details_list = []
    album_details = {"id": None, "title": None, "year": None, "release_count": None}

    #Loops through all release-groups in the JSON file 
    for item in json_file['release-groups']:

        album_details["id"]    = item["id"]
        album_details["title"] = item["title"]
        album_details["year"]  = item["first-release-date"].split("-")[0]
        album_details["release_count"] = collect_releases(item["id"], root_URL, delay)

        album_details_list.append(album_details.copy())   


    #Creates dictionary with all the albums of the artist    
    store_albums = {"albums": None}
    store_albums["albums"] = album_details_list

    #Paginates the dictionary 
    stored_paginated_albums = paginate(store_albums, offset , limit)

    #Returns JSON typed file containing the different albums arranged according to offset&limit
    return json.dumps(stored_paginated_albums)


#Runs the program and prints the JSON output as specified in the wording of the exercise 
print(post(MBID, offset, limit, delay = 1))
```

Comment: At the start, a time delay is fine but as you get more users you are going to need to find a different way so that users aren't waiting a few seconds for other users to get their requests sent back. As you scale, you could potentially talk to the owner of the API to discuss setting up more reasonable limits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JackMoody. It totally makes  sense, I guess the delay solution is unthinkable when you scale in users, as you say. That was why I thought there may be better ways of doing so (maybe using some `while` or `try`or something like that), in order to not wait 1 whole second if it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: If scaling to more users becomes an issue the best solution would probably to setup your own MusicBrainz database and use their data feed to keep up to date. Then you are not affected by any rate limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any nicer ways of dealing with this problem, other than asking the API owner to increase your rate limit. The only way to avoid a rate limit problem is by not making too many requests at a time, and besides hacking the API in such a way that you bypass its requests counter, you're stuck with waiting one second between each request.